# PetaPoco orm tool with Asp.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.0, petapoco

I am trying PetaPoco with my Asp.Net Project. How can I use PetaPoco with Asp.Net GridView. I am new at web programming.
I tried all code samples in the blog. They all are working with console app. But in Asp.Net I could not bind the datasource to GridView.

Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using PetaPoco;
using northwind;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace Mng
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public northwindDB db;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            db = new northwindDB();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                var q = db.Query<Product>("SELECT top 10 * FROM Products");
                grdMng.DataSource = q;

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Postback occurs");
            }
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call DataBind method to build the grid

```
grdMng.DataSource = q;
grdMng.DataBind();
```